# How to apply video filters from capture video in android

Tags: java, android, video, imagefilter

I'm trying to create an app where I am able to add color filters to a recorded video while  capturing the video from the camera .
Do you have steps / procedures / code / example on integrating video filters  on Android for the following needs.

I used to record the video,
then dividing it as frames and apply filters.

Comment: Well, I think the problem you'll face is the android camera callback gives you the frames after they've been sent to the view. Or are you saying you're actually recording it to file first?

Comment: exactly ...if you have any codes procedures to do that?

Comment: first capture the video  then split into frames after that  apply  filters (my concept is apply video filters from capture video)

Comment: Ramesh Kanan have u complete your video filtering yet?

Comment: did you succeed in your task ?

Comment: @loki did you find anything?